# Overrode delete behavior

Tags: c++

I'm creating an memory manager and for that, I'm overriding the `new` and `delete` operators.  When I use my custom `delete` which just prints to the screen the object is still destroyed.

```
void operator delete(void* pointer)
{
    //does nothing
    printf("overrode delete\n");
    //MemoryManager::get().deallocHeap(pointer);
}

struct X
{
    int xx;
    X(int x) : xx(x)
    {
        printf("x constructor\n");
    }

    ~X()
    {
        printf("x destructor\n");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    X* a = new X(20);
    delete a;
    getchar();      
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
x constructor
x destructor
overrode delete
```

If have no code except to print in `delete`, why is `X` destructor called?

Comment: Overriding `operator delete` only changes how object memory is deallocated. And destructor is always called when you use keyword `delete` (if your type has a destructor), no matter what code `operator delete` contains.

Comment: Now i got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global delete operator will be called for all classes in your code - probably needs a corresponding global new operator.

The destructor X (any class which has a destructor) is called whenever a class of that type is destroyed.  So `delete a;` causes it to be called (before the memory is released)

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking that override delete is same thing that override an class method.

Answer (score 1):

Here the operator delete which you are overriding in not exclusively used to print 
"overrode delete" but also used in the standard way it is implemented i.e. it deletes the object to which the pointer points to and hence the destructor is being called. Hence the delete operator is being used in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Because `delete a` is required to destroy `a` before freeing the memory it occupied by calling `operator delete`. In the same way that a new expression both allocates memory and then constructs an object in it.